# How to handle multiple FlatLists in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

[image]

These red marks areas are 3 `FlatLists`. The first and Second are horizontally scrolling `FlatLists` while the last `FlatList` is scrolling vertically.My problem arise when scrolling the last `FlatList`. It not going to the bottom it stays in the same position but scrolls (Like it has a fixed height). How to get rid of such thing. I'm trying a way to scroll the whole page. I have attached a GIF too to make sense. Thanks.

```
<SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}/>
//Top FLatList
<View>
  <FlatList
     showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
     horizontal
     data={articles}
     ...
  />
 </View>
//Middle FLatList
<View>
  <FlatList
     showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
     horizontal
     data={options}
     ...
  />
 </View>
 //Bottom FLatList
 <View>
  <FlatList
     data={articles}
     ...
  />
 </View>
</SafeAreaView>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is typically caused by the custome style to the bottom tab. You may fix it by adding the footer component prop to the last flatList.

```
//The total height including the bottom tab height and the space
   let bottomMargin = 110

 <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}/>
//Top FLatList
<View>
  <FlatList
     showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
     horizontal
     data={articles}
     ...
  />
 </View>
//Middle FLatList
<View>
  <FlatList
     showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
     horizontal
     data={options}
     ...
  />
 </View>
 //Bottom FLatList
 <View>
  <FlatList
     data={articles}
     ListFooterComponent={()=>(
      <FooterComponent/>
     )}
     ...
  />
 </View>
</SafeAreaView>


  const FooterComponent = () => {

    return (
        <View style={{marginBottom: bottomMargin}} />
    )
  }
```

**To scroll the whole page**

To scroll the entire page, pass the above code from the third flatlist as the Header component to the third flatlist like the following:

```
 <SafeAreaView style={{flex:1}}/>
//Top FLatList

 //Bottom FLatList
 <View>
  <FlatList
     data={articles}
     ListHeaderComponent={()=>(
      <HeaderComponent/>
     )}
     ...
  />
 </View>
</SafeAreaView>


  const HeaderComponent= () => {
    return (
      <View>
        <FlatList
         showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
         horizontal
         data={articles}
          />

         <FlatList
         showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
         horizontal
         data={options}
         />
     </View>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Actually I'm trying to scroll the whole page